# Why my fresh udon take so long to cook?

Tags: boiling, japanese-cuisine, noodles

I made fresh udon recently with 2:1 of flour and water ratio. rest it for 30 minutes before knead it with foot (folding and flatenvit by foot about 4-5 times), then rest it again for 2 hour before cutting. I cut the udon not to big, it’s just the normal size i usually eat from store bought udon. Most recipe says that it need to be cooked/boiled for 10-15 minutes. After I boiled my udon for 10 minutes the center part of the udon still have darker color and a bit hard. And i can taste the flour when I bite it. So i boiled it for another 10 minutes but it still the same. I boiled it until it marks 30 minutes. It got better but it still have that little darker and harder core in the middle. I wonder if it’s really took this long to cook fresh udon? or did i made it wrong?

Comment: And during this period, the water was actually at a rolling boil (with large, violent bubbles constantly rising and breaking on the surface)?

Comment: Also, are you at a significantly high altitude (more than 4000 feet or 1000 meters)?